# HTTP request web service function in jmeter

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, jmeter

I try calling a function from java web service, but have no idea about setting and how to write content of "body data".

WSDL locate: localhost:8080/OracleDB/WS?WSDL

function ReturnSet request no input and return List

In jmeter, I set IP=localhost, Port=8080, Path=/OracleDB/WS?WSDL, Method=POST
and Body Data to HTTP request

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
            <ReturnSet>
            </ReturnSet>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

It return can't found ReturnSet.

---

Update:

Thanks Dmitri T.

In SoapUI, it send XML like below, at header Content-Type set as "text/xml; charset=utf-8".
After those change, it work.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:uses="http://useSQL/">
    <soapenv:Header/>
        <soapenv:Body>
            <uses:ReturnSet/>
        </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to add [HTTP Header Manager](https://blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager) and add proper `Content-Type` and `SOAPAction` headers.

---

Another option is switching to [SOAP/XML-RPC Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#SOAP/XML-RPC_Request) sampler

Comment: ya, I have header manager with those two propers, Content-Type="text/xml; charset=utf-8", SOAPAction is blank as the tutorial in http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-ws-test-plan.html. At the below of SOAP/XML-RPC Request sampler, at WebService sampler, it says use HTTP request instead. It should work in HTTP request. or maybe you can show how it work in SOAP/XML-RPC Request.

Comment: I think correct content type should be `application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8'`. Check response using View Results Tree listener

Comment: well, It shows:  Response message: Unsupported Media Type.

Comment: According to https://www.w3.org/TR/soap12-part2/#tabreqstatereqtrans server is unhappy with your content type and/or encoding.

Comment: so, what should i do for it? redo the webservice to output the type?

Comment: Find out the right combination. Maybe with the help of [SoapUI](http://soapui.org/). I don't have OracleDB to play with hence cannot provide you the solution, only the direction to go.